# How can I determine the signal level needed into a given antenna to produce a given magnetic field at a given distance?

Tags: antenna

I have an ETS Lindgren 6511 loop antenna that lists a magnetic antenna factor of -2.5 (best I can read the graph) at our frequency of interest.

I've found lots of information on establishing a given electric field, but nothing that speaks specifically to magnetic fields.

Comment: If you have the electric field, you can calculate the magnetic field directly from it. Refer Antenna Design by Balanis, or Electromagnetism by Griffith. Check electromagnetic waves section.

Comment: I don't have access to a copy at this time.  I can order it, but surely there is a web page somewhere that has the formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have the electric fieldstrength, the rest is easy. The ratio of the electric and magnetic fieldstrength is called the [impedance of free space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impedance_of_free_space) its value is approximately 377 ohms.

So approximately: $$H = { E \over 377 } $$
H and E are the moduli of the respective field vectors.